# How to add folder reference(folder group) using xcode file template?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, templates, xcode9

I'm trying to create some template to simplify some boring repeating stuff in existing project.

I need to create something like entity and it's behavior classes, e.g. I want to add new entity "Hero" and I need the following structure in the end:

```
Entities/Hero/Hero.h
Entities/Hero/Hero.cpp
Entities/Hero/StateControllers/HeroStateController.h
Entities/Hero/StateControllers/HeroStateController.cpp
```

So I've created the following structure in my xcode template
[image: Template Folder Example]

The problem is when I use "New file..." and create "Hero" all files are added but folders are blue what means that this folder will be considered as assets folder. But I don't need it. I need it to be group referenced to folder(yellow one). I've searched the whole internet and could not find anything for file templates.

Can anybody please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did get something?

Comment: @JERC No. I left it as it is. I just made some note that it needs to be deleted from project and added again to consider folder as group referenced to folder. Also I've implemented python script since state controllers should be filled with some complex logic.